# ArrayList and strings

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have this question Write a static method which takes an ArrayList of Strings and an integer and changes the ArrayList destructively to remove all Strings whose length is less than the integer argument. i have this code so far could someone explain where I'm going wrong. it compiles but it doesn't remove any strings from the array list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class q4
// Shows adding a string after all occurrences of a string
// constructively in an ArrayList
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter some words (all on one line, separated by spaces):");
      String line = input.nextLine();
      String[] words = line.split(" +");
      ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
      {
         a.add(words[i]);
      }

      System.out.println("The words are stored in an ArrayList");
      System.out.println("The ArrayList is "+a);

      System.out.print("\nEnter a number");

      int len = input.nextInt();

      for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++)
      {
         String b =a.get(j);

         if(b.length()<len)
         {

            a.remove(j);

         }

      } 

      System.out.println("The ArrayList is "+a);

   }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an exception? Is the output wrong?

Comment: First place you're going wrong is slapping poorly formatted code into your browser and expecting help. Please indent properly so that people helping you don't have to do more work than is necessary to give you what you need.

Comment: I formatted your code OP, please accept the edits

Comment: Hi I'm new to here the help toolbar said to have 4 spacebars before each line of code. So thats what i have done.

Comment: thank you dreadheadeddeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an item of the ArrayList be sure to decrement "j". Also, although it is not common, set the for-condition to `j < a.size()`. Otherwise create a separate variable to store the size before the loop and then decrement it as well.
The following code should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter some words (all on one line, separated by spaces):");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = line.split(" +");
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {
        a.add(words[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("The words are stored in an ArrayList");
    System.out.println("The ArrayList is "+a);

    System.out.print("\nEnter a number");

    int len = input.nextInt();

    for(int j=0;j<a.size(); j++)
    {
        String b =a.get(j);

        if(b.length()<len)
        {

            a.remove(j);
            j--;
        }

    } 

    System.out.println("The ArrayList is "+a);
}
```

Comment: still the same error, when the array list prints at the end after removing items its still the same.

Comment: Did you copypaste the code from my answer or did you make all the changes I have made? Because it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You traverse the list from left to right and remove items as you go along. This causes a problem when removing multiple items, because the indices don't match any more.

This can be fixed quite easily by traversing the list from end to begin, instead of from begin to end.

Because now, if you remove an item, this doesn't affect the items to be removed later on:

```
for (int j = words.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

Comment: i think your way will mess up too. use an iterator directly. or keep the input ArrayList, move every string with length less than the integer to a new ArrayList instead.

Comment: hi i have tried this, still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3439272 why not iterate through using iterator and call `.remove()` instead?

Comment: @user3439272 you never even said what error you're getting. I just assumed it's an IndexOutOfBounds, which this solution fixes. Update your question with sample data and the Stacktrace it gives.

Comment: the array list basically remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class q4
// Shows adding a string after all occurrences of a string
// constructively in an ArrayList
{

   public static ArrayList<String> a;
   public static ArrayList<String> presenter;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter some words (all on one line, separated by spaces):");
      String line = input.nextLine();
      String[] words = line.split(" +");
      a = new ArrayList<String>();
      presenter = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
      {

         a.add(words[i]);

      }

      System.out.println("The words are stored in an ArrayList");
      System.out.println("The ArrayList is "+a);

      System.out.print("\nEnter a number");

      int len = input.nextInt();

      for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++)
      {

         String b =a.get(j);

         if((b.length()<len))
         {

            //do nothing

         }

         else
         {

            presenter.add(a.get(j));

         }

      } 

      System.out.print("The ArrayList is " + presenter);

   }
}
```

This is an alternative since you said the other codes didn't work, I simply transferred the "Good" data to another arraylist and printed out that one.